# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale in ggplot + geom_scatterpie

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I'm trying to do a map with ggplot and geom_scatterpie function but I'm keep receiving this error: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

the code is the following:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = my_raster, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = values)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "white", "white", "white", "grey", "white", "white"), na.value = "white", guide="none")  +
  geom_sf(data = europe_cropped, size = 0.1, color = "black", fill = "white", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = long, y = lat, r = 2), 
                  cols = colnames(my_table[2:5], color = "black",
                  data = my_table)  +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_few()
```

I've tried to run it without the geom_tile and scale_fill lines and it works but I need that raster as base of the map. What could be the problem the gives the error?

edit:

head(my_raster)

| x | y | focal_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -9.979089 | 64.98143 | 200 |
| -9.965076 | 64.98143 | 200 |
| -9.951063 | 64.98143 | 200 |
| -9.937050 | 64.98143 | 200 |
| -9.923037 | 64.98143 | 200 |
| -9.909024 | 64.98143 | 200 |

head(my_table)

| site | group1 | group2 | group3 | group4 | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site1 | 0.317 | 0 | 0.0448 | 0.280 | 47.7 | 5.08 |
| site2 | 0.370 | 0 | 0.0359 | 0.319 | 47.8 | 5.07 |
| site3 | 0.344 | 0 | 0.0269 | 0.233 | 47.8 | 5.12 |
| site4 | 0.317 | 0 | 0.00896 | 0.342 | 47.8 | 5.06 |
| site5 | 0.291 | 0 | 0.0538 | 0.373 | 47.8 | 5.04 |
| site6 | 0.476 | 0 | 0.0179 | 0.490 | 47.7 | 5.12 |

Comment: it's really hard to say much here, since we don't have the data that is causing your code to emit the error. Does removing just the scale_fill_gradientn line still cause the error?

Comment: unfortunately no, even with removing that line the error is still there. I think the problem occurs when I run both geom_tile and geom_scatterpie

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?